# What does |= mean

Tags: c++

What does **|=** mean in C++ ? I've found this snippet of code in the Net :

```
DWORD CDirWatcherDlg::GetChangeFlags1()
{

    DWORD dwChangeNotifyFlags = 0UL;
    FLAG_INFO arFlagInfo[]={
        {IDC_CHECK_FILE_NAME1,      FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME},
        {IDC_CHECK_DIR_NAME1,       FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME},
        {IDC_CHECK_LAST_WRITE1,     FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE},
        {IDC_CHECK_LAST_ACCESS1,    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS},
        {IDC_CHECK_SIZE1,           FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE},
        {IDC_CHECK_ATTRIBUTES1,     FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES},
        {IDC_CHECK_LAST_WRITE1,     FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE},
        {IDC_CHECK_LAST_ACCESS1,    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS},
        {IDC_CHECK_CREATION1,       FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION},
        {IDC_CHECK_SECURITY1,       FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY}
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arFlagInfo)/sizeof(arFlagInfo[0]); ++i)
    {
        dwChangeNotifyFlags |= (IsDlgButtonChecked(arFlagInfo[i].nCtrlId) == BST_CHECKED)? arFlagInfo[i].nFlag : 0;
    }

    return dwChangeNotifyFlags;
}
```

And I cannot understand what does this function.

Can someone explain this, please ?

Comment: `|=` it the same to `|` as `+=` to `+`.

Comment: can you please explain the full loop code, please ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means ["bitwise OR"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_OR#OR), it's also used in C, and works the same as `+=`

Say, for instance, that we have the following code:

```
char o = 0xF0;
o |= 0x0F;     //You can also write o = o|0x0F;
```

Now, `o` has the value `0xFF`:

```
 1111 0000 | 0000 1111   =   1111 1111
```

Let's try it again:

```
char o = 0xE1;  //1110 0001
o |= 0x08;      //0000 1000
```

And `o` now is:

```
1110 0001 | 0000 1000   =   1110 1001
```

Which is `0xE9`

Answer (score 0):

This is the bitwise OR assignment operator.

```
int a, int b;
// assign some values to a and b
a |= b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (a | b);
```

See [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/) for more info about the bitwise operators in C++.

In your code

```
dwChangeNotifyFlags |= (IsDlgButtonChecked(arFlagInfo[i].nCtrlId) == BST_CHECKED)? arFlagInfo[i].nFlag : 0;
```

means that `dwChangeNotifyFlags` is OR'd with `arFlagInfo[i].nFlag` if `IsDlgButtonChecked(arFlagInfo[i].nCtrlId) == BST_CHECKED` is true, and the result is assigned to `dwChangeNotifyFlags`. Otherwise, `dwChangeNotifyFlags` remains unchanged (because it's OR'd with 0).

Comment: Nope, that would happen if it used the bitwise AND assignment operator.

Comment: @maja OR-ing something with 0 leaves it unchanged.